# Perform action when JAX-RS/Java EE application is starting

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Is there some way to check when a JAX-RS/Java EE application is starting/deployed?

At these moment, I'd like to check whether a database is initialized. Otherwise, only if the database is not initialized, I need to initialize it, and I need to check it when the Java EE application starts.

So, I need to know if there is any way to catch when a JAX-RS/Java EE application starts.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I need to initialize it" - what exactly does that mean? Do you need to insert fixture data or something? Or create the schema? Or is this to do with setting up database connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least three ways to achieve it:

### Using [`ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) from the Servlet API

Since JAX-RS is built on the top of the Servlet API, the following piece of code will do the trick:

```java
@WebListener
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Perform action during application's startup
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Perform action during application's shutdown
    }
}
```

### Using [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) and [`@Observes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/event/Observes.html) from CDI

When using JAX-RS with CDI, you can have the following:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class StartupListener {

    public void init(@Observes 
                     @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext context) {
        // Perform action during application's startup
    }

    public void destroy(@Observes 
                        @Destroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext context) {
        // Perform action during application's shutdown
    }
}
```

Please note you must use [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) from the `javax.enterprise.context` package and not [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ApplicationScoped.html) from the `javax.faces.bean` package.

### Using [`@Startup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html) and [`@Singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) from EJB

When using JAX-RS with EJB, you can try:

```java
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupListener {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Perform action during application's startup
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // Perform action during application's shutdown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's probably not something you want to do, such things are probably best done in a bean with a `@Singleton` with `@Startup`, which can inject a database